# Exception getting server instance: No valid instance id for this instance

Tags: java, google-app-engine

When I change the logging level to `FINE` in my localhost Google App Engine app, I start seeing these in my trace stack:

```
Apr 17, 2013 4:54:20 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter getCurrentServerInstance
FINE: Exception getting server instance
com.google.appengine.api.labs.servers.ServersException: No valid instance id for this instance.
    at com.google.appengine.api.labs.servers.ServersServiceImpl.getCurrentInstanceId(ServersServiceImpl.java:75)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.getCurrentServerInstance(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:210)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.isServerLoadBalancingServerRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:185)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.getRequestType(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:174)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:112)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:421)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Any ideas what this is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known issue in the dev server:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10412

Has been known about for a while so I'm not sure if they are going to fix it.

Answer (score -3):

I think when you set the logging to FINE you should expect some spurious log messages. I'd set the logging level to FINE for your code only and leave the rest at the default level.

Comment: (Other than the author of the question) Please do not down-vote my answer until you have a better one.